# Consider not showing reputation change when showing the all time league?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

Showing the "reputation change" on the all-time league is confusing:

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/

```
Reputation Change
Rep Change* Users
10,000+ 14,624
5,000+  31,851
2,500+  64,634
1,000+  147,773
500+    259,400
250+    409,397
100+    436,988
50+ 436,988
1+  436,988

Total Reputation
Total Rep*  Users
100,000+    649
50,000+ 1,864
25,000+ 4,840
10,000+ 14,624
5,000+  31,851
3,000+  54,008
2,000+  80,386
1,000+  147,773
500+    259,400
200+    436,988
1+  9,749,334
```

Note that the numbers are exactly the same for 10,000 and 500 etc.